# We have a template; how do you save as a WIKI page to actually use the template?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, wiki, template

We are creating a book, each page We have a template that was created of a WIKI page using SharePoint 2013... I would like to 'save as' the page and rename it (over and over with about 20 different pages) and give it specific edits can't find a 'save as' feature.